# Hibernate, hql, count with join fetch generates select with all fields and count, why?

Tags: hibernate, jpql

I have a hql query like this:

```
  return (long)Session.CreateQuery (" select count(*) " +
                                      "   from Files p " +
                                      "   join fetch p.Application a " +
                                      "  where a.Name = :AppName")
                        .SetParameter("AppName", application)                            
                        .UniqueResult();
```

Hibernate creates sql query like this:

```
   select field1, field2, field3, count(*)
```

That's why it cannot be executed.

Why select count(*) makes hibernate to list all fields and how to prevent it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the problem comes with the use of '`FETCH`', which is normally used to get the dependencies of a given entity from the database. So Hibernate queries the fields of Application to create the objects.

If you only want to count the files associated to an application, change '`JOIN FETCH`' for '`INNER JOIN`' (or simply '`JOIN`'). The only queried field should be `count(*)` then.